# XCode iDevice app - How to listen for message/request from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services

I have a project where I need to be able to send messages from a server running a web service to a specific iDevice. I have no idea how to do this, so any help is very appreciated.

The scenario: I have a web service which receives some message from an iDevice (could also be a Mac or PC, even an Android device). Depending on the content of this message I need to be able to send a message from the web service to another iDevice (I know the IP-address of the specific iDevice). I know how to use URLRequests to send a message from an iDevice to a server and collect the response from the server. In principle I could every 10 seconds send a request to the server asking if the server has any new messages to the sender (the iDevice sending the request), but I am pretty sure this is not the correct way to do it. Is there a way to have an iDevice listen for server communication on a specific port, so that the iDevice only does something active when it receives a message from the server to do something, e.g. display a message in the app listening for the server communication?

I guess I need to use something similar to the technology used for iMessage, but how is this done?

I am using XCode 4.6.2, iOS 6.1.

EDIT: Just to clarify my needs a bit more: The APNS seems to be TOO unreliable (at least that is what I have read in other threads regarding APN) as the web service in some cases can have the need for sending 2 distinct message to an iDevice within 1 minute (in some cases seconds), and as far as I have read in other threads this will simply not be possible because of how Apple's server handles ASPNS.

The app i am developing only needs to receive messages from the server when the app is active - is there any way, not using APNs, to do this, e.g. making the app listen for communication on a specific port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I have decided not to use the APNS, because it seems like people are having all sort of experience with it. I cannot use APNS because my project needs 100 % reliability and instant communication with the server.

I have decided to use tcp communication since my project only will be used in a local network. This will obviously mean more power consumption on the iDevices, but reliability is more crucial to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario seems pretty similar to APPLE PUSH NOTIFICATIONs (APNs).

Ideally your server side should write a code in such a way that if there is any change on server side & need to be informed to all associated devices.

Then your server should post notification Apple server which will then send a notification to all the associated devices.

[Refer this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)

You already have but can use this code to identify the iOS/Mac deivce

```
NSString *identifierString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myID"];
if (!identifierString) {
    CFUUIDRef identifier = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    identifierString = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, identifier);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:identifierString forKey:@"myID"];
}
NSLog(@"%@",identifierString);
```

this code works till the lifetime of the app only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. APNS sounds very promising, but I am pretty concerned about one thing regarding the APNS - the reliability and how the Apple server just dumps notifications if it reaches timeout. Do you know if there exist any statistics on percentages of APNS not getting delivered, because the APNS (server->iDevice communication) will be extremely crucial for my App.

Comment: I know how the acceptance works, but I am not sure if the APN is the best solution, based on what other developers experience are. I will investigate the APN a bit further and come back to this question later.