# How do I listen to the APN Feedback Server using the Zend Framework?

Tags: php, push-notification, zend-framework2, apple-push-notifications

To be honest, I'm not quite *the* back-end developer, so I don't how to do this properly.

I want to use the Zend Framework 2.x.x to send push notifications to both iOS and Android. I understand most of the content [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mobile.push.apns.html), so I believe I can easily send push notifications to devices now.

The thing I'm stuck now is implementing the listener. Quoting the text:

> APNS has a feedback service that you must listen to. Apple states that
>   they monitor providers to ensure that they are listening to this
>   service.
>
> The feedback service simply returns an array of device tokens and the
>   time. You can use the time to ensure that the device has not
>   re-registered for push notifications since the last send.

Attached this code below:

```
$apns = new Zend_Mobile_Push_Apns();
$apns->setCertificate('/path/to/provisioning-certificate.pem');

try {
    $apns->connect(Zend_Mobile_Push_Apns::SERVER_FEEDBACK_SANDBOX_URI);
} catch (Zend_Mobile_Push_Exception_ServerUnavailable $e) {
    // you can either attempt to reconnect here or try again later
    exit(1);
} catch (Zend_Mobile_Push_Exception $e) {
    echo 'APNS Connection Error:' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

$tokens = $apns->feedback();
while(list($token, $time) = each($tokens)) {
    echo $time . "\t" . $token . PHP_EOL;
}
$apns->close();
```

I actually understand how it works and what I'm supposed to do with the feedback the server returns. What I don't know is how is this script exactly "listening" to the Apple Push Notification Feedback Server? I don't think I can just slap in this code in a file and miraculously expect Apple's server to find it. How do I continually "listen" to the feedback server so this script gets called whenever Apple requires it?

Comment: The web server does the listening bit, so it looks like the idea is to use this code to reply to a request from the Apple server. I'm not an iOS dev, but I would guess you would set up your listener URL in your Apple developer account.

Comment: Possibly useful: [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=listen+to+apple+apn+request+url) pointed to [this resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480320/xcode-idevice-app-how-to-listen-for-message-request-from-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple is not calling your script. Your script calls Apple's Feedback Service periodically (for example, once every day - you decide how often to run the script). Then you process the device tokens returned by the Feedback Service and remove obsolete Device Tokens from your DB.

> Query the feedback service daily to get the list of device tokens. Use
>   the timestamp to verify that the device tokens haven’t been
>   reregistered since the feedback entry was generated. For each device
>   that has not been reregistered, stop sending notifications. APNs
>   monitors providers for their diligence in checking the feedback
>   service and refraining from sending push notifications to nonexistent
>   applications on devices.

You can read more about the Feedback Service [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3).

Comment: Haha, what I understand with "listening" is that Apple will eventually call my script. If it's the other way around, should I just set a cron job for this and execute it every 24 hours or so?

Comment: @AndyIbanez Yes, setting a cron job to execute the script periodically will do the trick.